# django runserver command erro

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

OS: Windows 10

Now, for the project where the runserver command works I get this:
Here is my project structure. i have install all the requirements for this project but still getting this error. I've found something where there were errors with the run server command, but none were satisfying. If this is a duplicate, I do apologies, but I'm pretty sure it isn't. If there's a need for other files and snippets of code, I'll put here everything. Thank you so much.

```
 D:.
    |   main.py
    |
    |   README.md
    |   
    +---BLL
    |   |   asgi.py
    |   |   requirements.txt
    |   |   settings.py
    |   |   urls.py
    |   |   wsgi.py
    |   |   __init__.py
    |   |   
    |   \---__pycache__
    |           settings.cpython-37.pyc
    |           settings.cpython-39.pyc
    |           urls.cpython-37.pyc
    |           urls.cpython-39.pyc
    |           __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    |           __init__.cpython-39.pyc
    |           
    +---DAL
    |   |   db.sqlite3
    |   |   __init__.py
    |   |   
    |   +---account
    |   |   |   admin.py
    |   |   |   apps.py
    |   |   |   forms.py
    |   |   |   models.py
    |   |   |   tests.py
    |   |   |   views.py
    |   |   |   __init__.py
    |   |   |   
    |   |   +---migrations
    |   |   |   |   0001_initial.py
    |   |   |   |   __init__.py
    |   |   |   |   
    |   |   |   \---__pycache__
    |   |   |           0001_initial.cpython-38.pyc
    |   |   |           __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    |   |   |           
    |   |   \---__pycache__
    |   |           admin.cpython-37.pyc
    |   |           admin.cpython-38.pyc
    |   |           admin.cpython-39.pyc
    |   |           apps.cpython-37.pyc
    |   |           apps.cpython-38.pyc
    |   |           apps.cpython-39.pyc
    |   |           forms.cpython-38.pyc
    |   |           models.cpython-37.pyc
    |   |           models.cpython-38.pyc
    |   |           models.cpython-39.pyc
    |   |           views.cpython-38.pyc
    |   |           __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    |   |           __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    |   |           __init__.cpython-39.pyc
    |   |           
    |   \---chatbot
    |       |   admin.py
    |       |   apps.py
    |       |   data.pickle
    |       |   loadAI.py
    |       |   models.py
    |       |   session.json
    |       |   tests.py
    |       |   trainAI.py
    |       |   views.py
    |       |   __init__.py
    |       |   
    |       +---migrations
    |       |       0001_initial.py
    |       |       __init__.py
    |       |       
    |       +---model
    |       |       testmodel.h5
    |       |       
    |       \---__pycache__
    |               admin.cpython-37.pyc
    |               admin.cpython-39.pyc
    |               apps.cpython-37.pyc
    |               apps.cpython-39.pyc
    |               models.cpython-37.pyc
    |               models.cpython-39.pyc
    |               trainAI.cpython-37.pyc
    |               trainAI.cpython-39.pyc
    |               views.cpython-37.pyc
    |               views.cpython-39.pyc
    |               __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    |               __init__.cpython-39.pyc
    |               
    +---TESTS
    |       test.py
    |       
    \---UI
        |   admin.py
        |   apps.py
        |   models.py
        |   tests.py
        |   urls.py
        |   views.py
        |   __init__.py
        |   
        +---images
        |       1.PNG
        |       10.PNG
        |       2.PNG
        |       3.PNG
        |       4.PNG
        |       5.PNG
        |       6.PNG
        |       7.PNG
        |       8.PNG
        |       9.PNG
        |       chatbot.GIF
        |       
        +---static
        |   \---UI
        |       +---audio
        |       |       audio0.mp3
        |       |       audio1.mp3
        |       |       audio2.mp3
        |       |       audio3.mp3
        |       |       
        |       +---css
        |       |       css-main.css
        |       |       css-responsive.css
        |       |       
        |       \---images
        |               bg.jpg
        |               landscape1.jpg
        |               logo.ico
        |               logo.jpg
        |               user.png
        |               
        +---templates
        |   \---UI
        |       |   base.html
        |       |   index.html
        |       |   
        |       +---errors
        |       |       404.html
        |       |       500.html
        |       |       
        |       \---pages
        |               about.html
        |               account.html
        |               changepass-done.html
        |               changepass.html
        |               chatbot.html
        |               FAQs.html
        |               login.html
        |               signup.html
        |               update.html
        |               
        \---__pycache__
                admin.cpython-37.pyc
                admin.cpython-39.pyc
                apps.cpython-37.pyc
                apps.cpython-39.pyc
                models.cpython-37.pyc
                models.cpython-39.pyc
                urls.cpython-37.pyc
                urls.cpython-39.pyc
                views.cpython-37.pyc
                views.cpython-39.pyc
                __init__.cpython-37.pyc
                __init__.cpython-39.pyc
```

I have clone this project from git hub when i use `python main.py runserver` command it givs me this error:

```
D:\Covid19Chatbot-master>python main.py runserver
        Watching for file changes with StatReloader
        Performing system checks...
        
        2021-01-22 17:20:47.257952: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
        2021-01-22 17:20:47.263540: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
        [nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to
        [nltk_data]     C:\Users\mehra\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
        [nltk_data]   Package punkt is already up-to-date!
        Exception in thread django-main-thread:
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
            self.run()
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
            self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
            self.check(display_num_errors=True)
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 395, in check
            include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
            return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
            new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
            return check_resolver(resolver)
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
            return check_method()
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in check
            for pattern in self.url_patterns:
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
            res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
            patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
            res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
            return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "D:\Covid19Chatbot-master\BLL\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
            path('', include('UI.urls')),
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
            urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "D:\Covid19Chatbot-master\UI\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
            from chatbot.views import (
          File "D:\Covid19Chatbot-master\DAL\chatbot\views.py", line 6, in <module>
            ai = TrainAI()
          File "D:\Covid19Chatbot-master\DAL\chatbot\trainAI.py", line 24, in __init__
            jsonContent = json.loads(res.content.decode())
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
            return _default_decoder.decode(s)
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
            obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
            raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
        json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: can you post the views.py and the json it is using

Comment: @Sirwill98 github code link https://github.com/CoDev-20/Covid19Chatbot

Answer (score 0):

The Error is from Lines 22-24 in trainAI

```
    website = r"https://coronavirus-ph-api.herokuapp.com/total/"
    res = requests.get(website)
    jsonContent = json.loads(res.content.decode())
```

this website has no content and returns no json, thats why it cannot iterate through it and throws an error

Comment: any alternative??

Comment: im not sure even what the JSON is, recommendations are off topic for stack overflow also